# curl: /usr/local/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: no version information available

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl, markup

In Ubuntu 14.04 when I try to use curl I get the below messages:

```
curl www.google.com
curl: /usr/local/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
curl: /usr/local/lib/liblber-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
```

curl version:

```
curl --version

curl: /usr/local/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
curl: /usr/local/lib/liblber-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4)
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

any one else has experienced this issue?

Answer (score 3):

This error means libcurl was compiled with a version of `libldap_r` other than what you have in `/usr/local/lib`.

As a solution you can create a symbolic links for missing files:

```
$ sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/liblber-2.4.so.2 /usr/local/lib/ 
$ sudo ln -fs /usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 /usr/local/lib/
```